# Как создать конструктор в наследнике с параметрами, не соответствующие параметрам базового конструктора

Tags: c#, наследование, конструктор

Есть конструктор в базовом классе

```
public Kons(int a, string b){}
```

Нужно сделать конструктор в наследнике

```
public Nasl(int a, int[] c):base(a,b){}
```

Пишет что для нестатического поля b требуется ссылка на объект. Статическим b сделать нельзя. Что делать?

Comment: А что вы имеете ввиду под b, когда пишете `base(a, b)`?

Comment: у конструктора скоуп видимости это константы, статические поля/свойства и параметры которые передают в конструктор явно, в данном случае (a, c).
Если нужно передать еще b - он либо должен передаваться через конструктор наряду с (a,c), либо уже должен быть объявлен как статический или как константа и быть доступным текущему классу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в конструктор наследника добавить третий параметр b, имеющиий значение по умолчанию:

```
public BaseConstructor (int a, string b) 
{
...
}
public NaslConstructor (int a, int[] c, string b = "defaultString")
: base (a, b)
{
...
}
```

Или если эта строка у наследника одинаковая, то можно использовать константную строку:

```
public BaseConstructor (int a, string b) 
{
...
}
public NaslConstructor (int a, int[] c)
: base (a, "constString")
{
...
}
```